# blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0

Tags: arch-linux, hard-disk, error-handling

I recently started noticing some `blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0` errors on my second computer running Arch Linux that I use as a server. This began when I had to reboot the computer when I moved into a new apartment. I had the following `/etc/fstab` configuration:

```
#
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=94880e53-c4d3-4d4d-a217-84c9ac58f4fd
/dev/sda1       /       ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered        0 1

#UUID=c1245aca-bbf7-4813-8c25-10bd0d95631e
/dev/sda2       none    swap    defaults        0 0

#UUID=94880e53-c4d3-4d4d-a217-84c9ac58f4fd
/dev/sdb1       /media/marcel/videos    auto    rw,user,auto    0 0
```

So my main hdd gets mounted to `/` and my external hdd get mounted to `/media/marcel/videos`. The problem is that after the reboot, my external drive got `/dev/sda` and my internal drive got `/dev/sdb`. The computer booted fine as far as I could tell until I looked into `/media/marcel/videos` which was a clone of `/`. Now I have the external drive unplugged and I am just trying to troubleshoot my main drive.

Relavent `dmesg`:

```
ACPI Error: [CAPB] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160108/dsfield-211)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0._OSC] (Node ffff88007b891708), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160108/psparse-542)
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, Evaluating _DOD (20160108/video-1248)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001028-0x000000000000102F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001028-0x0000000000001047 (\_SB.PCI0.IEIT.EITR) (20160108/utaddress-255)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001028-0x000000000000102F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000000102F (\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.PMIO) (20160108/utaddress-255)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001180-0x00000000000011AF (\_SB.PCI0.LPC0.GPOX) (20160108/utaddress-255)
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
```

`fdisk -l` (whenever I run `fdisk -l`, I get the `blk_update_request` error again):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007ee23

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 311609343 311607296 148.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       311609344 312581807    972464 474.9M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux nas 4.5.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat May 7 20:43:57 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is this a serious issue or something that can be ignored?

Edit 1:

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              491520  0
rfkill                 20480  2 cfg80211
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             180224  0
psmouse               118784  0
kvm                   491520  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_hda_codec_analog    16384  1
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_analog
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
gpio_ich               16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
ppdev                  20480  0
led_class              16384  1 input_leds
pcspkr                 16384  0
evdev                  24576  3
joydev                 20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
snd_hda_intel          32768  0
snd_hda_codec         106496  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog
i2c_i801               20480  0
snd_hda_core           49152  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                86016  3 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
mei_me                 32768  0
i915                 1155072  1
mei                    81920  1 mei_me
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65536  7 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog
intel_agp              20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
fjes                   28672  0
drm_kms_helper        106496  1 i915
e1000e                217088  0
drm                   290816  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
parport_pc             28672  0
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
parport                40960  2 ppdev,parport_pc
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
button                 16384  1 i915
video                  36864  1 i915
intel_gtt              20480  3 i915,intel_agp
acpi_cpufreq           20480  1
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
tpm_tis                20480  0
tpm                    36864  1 tpm_tis
processor              32768  1 acpi_cpufreq
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               28672  1 ip_tables
ext4                  516096  1
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
mbcache                20480  1 ext4
jbd2                   94208  1 ext4
sr_mod                 24576  0
cdrom                  49152  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 36864  3
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 45056  0
hid                   114688  2 hid_generic,usbhid
atkbd                  24576  0
libps2                 16384  2 atkbd,psmouse
ata_piix               36864  2
ehci_pci               16384  0
floppy                 69632  0
ata_generic            16384  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
i8042                  24576  1 libps2
serio                  20480  6 serio_raw,atkbd,i8042,psmouse
uhci_hcd               40960  0
libata                196608  3 pata_acpi,ata_generic,ata_piix
ehci_hcd               69632  1 ehci_pci
usbcore               196608  4 uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
scsi_mod              151552  3 libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
```

Comment: So are you saying that the `blk_update_request` errors are coming from my floppy drive? If that's the case, that's really weird because I don't even have a floppy drive.

Comment: Related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/213512/119991

Comment: Related: [blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0](https://askubuntu.com/q/719058/78223).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that kernel erroneously detected some device as floppy or just created a non existent reference because your machine does not have real floppy drive. So these `blk_update_request` for `fd0` are completely unrelated to your hard drives.
Many disk managing programs such as `fdisk` like to enumerate all available block devices, and definitely `fdisk` did hit floppy module and these messages started to appear in your dmesg.

Since your machine does not have floppy drive, it is safe and encouraged to remove and blacklist `floppy` kernel module so it will not bother you in future:

```
sudo rmmod floppy
echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf
```

then add `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf` to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` FILES variable and do `mkinitcpio -p linux` so initramfs will not load it too.

So after next reboot it will not appear and mess your steady configuration.

Comment: Do note that if your system has a floppy controller, it can't know until it tries to probe it if there's a drive attached, and it can't really tell the difference very well between "empty drive" and "no drive".  That's why you have to blacklist the module to get rid of the error if you don't have a drive.

Answer (score 7):

Use the below command and it will fix the problem for sure:

```
# sudo rmmod floppy
# echo "blacklist floppy" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-floppy.conf
# update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Reboot...

Answer (score 2):

I have been fiddling and fooling around with that for yet rather a long time. A short and a long solution.

### This is the short one

- First see that your **fstab** file is okay, especially your **swap** file.
- Than run:

  ```
    sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```

  and your problems should be over.

### The long version

The long version written by someone else which I did not take note of. (Sorry people!)

Try:

- Use `blkid` to determine the `UUID` of your swap partition, and while at it, make sure all other partitions have correct `UUID`'s in `/etc/fstab`. Also can use `lsblk -f` to find the `UUID`'s.
- Put the correct `UUID`'s into `/etc/fstab`, especially swap, for this error.
- Put the correct `UUID` for swap into `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.
- Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Reboot. Fixed my triple boot of Stretch all with this error, as the swap file had changed.

### Explanation for the long version

The problem was due to my swap being encrypted. So the `local-premount` script in initramfs was waiting for a swap device that was not available, until it timed out. The relevant message was gave up waiting for suspend/resume device.

To disable this (as resuming from swap is not possible with an encrypted swap, and I don't use hibernation anyway), I modified this file: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

- In this file, a line with

  ```
   RESUME=none
  ```

(instead of the UUID that was here) will disable waiting for a resume device.

- Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to apply the changes.
- System now boots normally.

Bert

Comment: Thanks, in my case it works. I have changed UUID in /etec/fstab but I forget about /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume and that was a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=133253

It solves this bug which wasn't obviously in my case a floppy initialization bug rather than a new partition UUID (like new UUID for swap partition).

Btw: It's not necessary to change in /boot/grub/grub.cfg from "root=UUID=" to "root=/dev/sd??".