# What "ACPI Warning: SystemIO range ... conflicts with OpRegion" means and how should I fix it?

Tags: acpi

I found this in my kernel logs:

```
kernel: ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000295-0x0000000000000296 conflicts 
with OpRegion 0x0000000000000290-0x0000000000000299 (\AMW0.SHWM) (20201113/utaddress-204)
```

What does it mean and how should I fix it?

```bsh
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282845/blk-update-request-i-o-error-dev-fd0-sector-0

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure how that would help

Comment: You could investigate the answer(s) and see if any of them help your situation. [edit] your question if there's additional information that might be helpful, or to distinguish your situation from similar ones.

Comment: thanks, I already investigated and I would gladly add more information to the question if I'd have